# Why is the performance of these scripts so different?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

We are trying to migrate ~650 million records to a new database on the same server and are seeing extremely discrepant performance between the two alternatives being tested right now.  The first script is below, and uses a reference table with beginning and end time intervals and a cursor to build out insert statements.  The alternative is using the same reference table to actually create ~26000 unique insert statements and executing them.

Option 1 (ran for 16 hours and only moved ~2% of total records):

```
--Declare scoped variables
DECLARE @migStart datetime, @migEnd datetime;

--Set up cursor for reference intervals
DECLARE migCur CURSOR FOR
SELECT dttm_interval_start, dttm_interval_end
FROM DBA.dbo.intervalReference
WHERE complete = 0
ORDER BY dttm_interval_start;

OPEN migCur;

--Initialize the cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM migCur
INTO @migStart, @migEnd;

--Iterate through the reference intervals
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN

    --Move the records as >= start and < end
    INSERT INTO NEW.dbo.new_log(field1, field2, field3, ......, field19)
    SELECT field1, field2, field3, ......, field19
    FROM OLD.dbo.old_log
    WHERE log_dt >= @migStart and log_dt < @migEnd;

    --Mark the interval as done, capture record count
    UPDATE DBA.dbo.intervalReference
    SET complete = 1, records = @@ROWCOUNT
    WHERE dttm_interval_start = @migStart and dttm_interval_end = @migEnd;

    --Fetch the next cursor item
    FETCH NEXT FROM migCur
    INTO @migStart, @migEnd;

END;

CLOSE migCur;
DEALLOCATE migCur;
GO
```

Option 2 (our calculations project this one to finish in ~65 hours total.  There are ~26000 of these, each one covers a different time interval.)

```
INSERT INTO new.dbo.new_log(field1, field2, field3, ......, field19)
    SELECT field1, field2, field3, ......, field19
    FROM OLD.dbo.old_log
    WHERE log_dt >= '2013-02-17 12:00:00.000' and log_dt < '2013-02-17 14:00:00.000';
```

I understand that cursors are not performant, but are they really so bad that I can't even use them to iterate through a reference table to control query bounds?

I have looked at the execution plan for the script vs the individual insert statements and the number of records expected for option 1 at the insert step is ~190 million, way more than the 140k record batch size we calculated the time intervals around.  Could it be that the statistics are misleading the engine about the best way to optimize?

Do queries in loops get optimized?

Why is Option 2 so much more performant than Option 1?

Comment: My guess is that the problem is parameter sniffing caused by migStart and migEnd values being unknown when the plan is done, and the estimation of how many rows will be found can be totally wrong -- and that can cause totally wrong plan to be used. You could check if adding "option (recompile)" helps or not.

Comment: @JamesZ Interesting, it seems that should make it behave more like option 2, in that a new execution plan would be calculated prior to each run of the loop.  Thanks for your input.

Comment: Have you tried adding fast_forward to the cursor?

Comment: @ErikEJ No I haven't, I will look into that as well but I think the problem lies in the plan, not the cursor.  I used a cursor to populate the reference table with the interval bounds and saw 56000 inserts in 30 seconds.

Comment: With that much data I suspect that neither option is going to be good from a performance perspective. the cursor is awful because it has to iterate over 650 million rows one at a time. This will never be very fast. The second option is a problem because the log file has to track a MOUNTAIN of information for 650 million rows. You should do this in batches instead. The technique is to use a loop but inside the loop you do batches of 50-100k rows at a time. This eases the pressure on the transaction log.

Comment: @SeanLange The cursor is defined against the reference table, not the target data table.  The database are in simple mode at the moment, so inserts are not being written to the transaction log.  I feel like Option 1 already strives for the batching technique you mention, the intervals in the reference table were calculated to keep the counts between 100k - 150k.  How would I achieve proper batching without losing my cursor definition after the first batch?

Comment: Yes inserts are written the transaction log. They must be to maintain ACID. If they weren't written to the transaction log you wouldn't be able to rollback an insert statement.

Comment: @SeanLange Ok, but isn't Option 1 an implementation of the batching technique you mentioned?  The intervals in the reference table are calculated to keep the result set sizes between 100k and 150k.  Unfortunately, I don't think JamesZ's idea about OPTION (RECOMPILE) would help here because even if we make the plans disposable, the parameters will always be unknown when the new plan is calculated.  Correct?

Comment: It looks like it might be a batching type of process but from just this portion it is hard to say for sure. Copying 650 million rows is going to be slow no matter how you do this.